# Jackson dynamic/custom deserialization of nested object based on multiple fields at different nest levels

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

Firstly thank you for your time!
Any hints would be highly appreciated on how to do this with Jackson

```json
{
  "operation": "create|update|delete|etc",
  "key": {"type": "type1", "id": "1" },
  "payload": { //fields that are specific to **operation and key.type** at the same time },
  "...": // other fields based only on operation
}
```

I've tried doing this with annotations only, and I managed to get the root object deserialized based on the operation type using `@JsonTypeInfo`, and managed to get the key and the other fields to work with it as well using the `external_property` mode, but can't figure out a way to get the payload out correctly. If there is a way to achieve this solely with annotations, please do tell :)

After, I tried creating a custom deserializer for the root object, manually parsed the top fields by inspecting the operation property, getting to a point similar to the annotations only approach, but got stuck again on the payload.

```java
@JsonSubTypes(Type(Type1CreatePayload.class))
sealed interface CreatePayload {}

@JsonTypeName("type1") // matches key.type
final record Type1CreatePayload(..)

sealed abstract class Operation {
  // operation field
  // key object
}

final class CreateOperation<P extends CreatePayload> extends Operation {
  P payload;
}
```

**I can't figure out how to find the type reference or java type from the DeserializerContext or parser, so I can reuse @JsonTypeName annotations from subtypes to dynamically call parser.readValueAs(type).**

Also during my research I've seen wiki links that are now dead any ideas where the official docs are? espcially for custom serializers(error handling / reporting), @JsonTypeDeserializer etc. as I feel this is more complicated than usual usage patterns.